# Camera Permission inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, camera, media, navigator

I have an website (let's say A) which embeds another website (let's say B) in an iframe. Now website B uses camera for the video chat. When I run website B separately it ask's for camera permission but when it is in an iframe it gives me the error that camera is not accessible? So how we can get camera permission inside iframe ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the "Feature Policy" of the iFrame helps!

Let's say your iframe's ID is "F"...

```
 F.setAttribute('allow','microphone; camera');
```

Once this attribute is set on the iframe, you can then load it.